# What is lower and higher bits?

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bit

Can anyone tell me what is lower and higher bits?. How to identify a higher and lower bit?. Below is binary form. How does `0110` is higher bit in it?.

```
0110 0111 1100 1010 1100 0111 1001 1011
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just like in decimal, higher places are generally written to the left in binary. So if you see `0111`, the `0` is the high bit. So this would represent 7 in decimal. The same applies when spaces are used, just like when commas (or dots, depending on your locale) are used to separate groups of digits in decimal.

Comment: Is the highest bit is 0110 which starts with 0 and the lowest bit is one which starts with 1... which is on right 1011...

Comment: @Shane: Sorry, I don't understand your question. The most significant bit in the group is on the left, just like the most significant digit in decimal. The least significant bit is on the right, just like the least significant digit in decimal.

Comment: One final question, can you post an example of the decimal with least and high significant digit... which will make me understand fully... thanks

Comment: "42,103" Here, '4' is the most significant digit because it represents tens of thousands. '3' is the least significant digit since it only represents units. Notice that the command doesn't matter -- it just makes the numbers easier to read.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz isnt the highest bit the '0' on the left and lowest bit the '1' on the right? Since bit is a 0 or 1 how can 0110 be highest bit

Comment: @rimiro 0110 are the highest bits, each of them higher than any of the bits to the right. Just like in "42,103", "42" are the most significant and "103" as less.